# C# Объект любого класса в конструкторе

Tags: c#

Я не силён, пытаюсь понять как это можно реализовать.

Нужно чтобы конструктор метода принимал объект любого класса, но как это записать?

```
public interface ISaveAndLoad
{
   void Save(int indexToSave, //Класс);
   void Load(int indexToLoad);
}
```

Comment: Для таких целей в C# есть так называемые [Универсальные методы](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods). Конкретно ваш код можно тогда переписать так: `void Save<T>(int indexToSave, T value) where T : class;`, использование будет тогда `.Save(1, new SomeClass());`, где `SomeClass` - любой другой класс.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public interface ISaveAndLoad<T>
{
    void Save(int indexToSave, T obj);
    void Load(int indexToLoad);
}
```

ИЛИ

```
public interface ISaveAndLoad
{
    void Save(int indexToSave, object obj);
    void Load(int indexToLoad);
}
```

ИЛИ

```
public interface ISaveAndLoad
{
    void Save<T>(int indexToSave, T obj);
    void Load(int indexToLoad);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Возьмите `Object` и живите спокойно